# Webpage does not have the correct size in my UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

When i load a specific URL in Safari, the page is shown correctly...means small and the whole page fits the screen, so that i dont have to scroll horizontal.
When i load the same URL in my UIWebView, the Webpage appears very large. So if it appears on a desktop PC. How can i solve this problem? Why des it appear so large and in Safari on iPhone all is ok?

I use this line of code to load the page

```
[self.newsWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<URL GOES HERE>"]]];
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scaleToFit property of the UIWebView to YES. You can do that in code or use the interface builder (there's a scaleToFit tick box for the WebView).

Comment: Thank you, i found it out myself. i did it in the code 'self.myWebView.scalesPageTopFit'